# How to add unmanaged jars to build.sbt generated by a g8 template?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am working on libgdx/android project in Scala. I have build.sbt generated by libgdx-sbt-project.g8 template. I am trying to add a jar file. Could somebody help me out?
Here is the code:

```
lazy val android = common ++ Tasks.natives ++ Seq(
versionCode := 0,
keyalias := "change-me",
platformName := "android-19",
mainAssetsPath in Compile := file("common/assets"),
unmanagedJars in Compile <+= (libraryJarPath) (p => Attributed.blank(p)) map( x=> x),
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx-backend-android" % "0.9.9",
  "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx-platform" % "0.9.9" % "natives" classifier "natives-armeabi",
  "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx-platform" % "0.9.9" % "natives" classifier "natives-armeabi-v7a"
),
nativeExtractions <<= (baseDirectory) { base => Seq(
  ("natives-armeabi.jar", new ExactFilter("libgdx.so"), base / "lib" / "armeabi"),
  ("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar", new ExactFilter("libgdx.so"), base / "lib" / "armeabi-v7a")
)})
```

I am new with Scala and SBT. I don't quite understand this syntax:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile <+= (libraryJarPath) (p => Attributed.blank(p)) map( x=> x)
```

Comment: Regarding the point where you say you don't understand the syntax, check my answer to [Use cases for different sbt Key operators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23693921/480975)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the jar(s) to the directory pointed by `libraryJarPath`, `reload` the project and you should have them on `Compile` classpath.

To query for the value of the `libraryJarPath` setting execute `show libraryJarPath` in sbt shell.

It'd be quite helpful if you shared the project on GitHub so it'd be easier to help out.

### Trying out libgdx-sbt-project.g8 myself

Provided you work with [ajhager/libgdx-sbt-project.g8](https://github.com/ajhager/libgdx-sbt-project.g8) project template with the defaults:

```
~/sandbox/so
▶ g8 ajhager/libgdx-sbt-project
package [my.game.pkg]:
name [My Game]:
scala_version [2.10.3]:
api_level [19]:
libgdx_version [0.9.9]:

Template applied in ./my-game

~/sandbox/so
▶ cd my-game
```

I would first update sbt used in the project:

```
sandbox/so/my-game
▶ cat project/build.properties
sbt.version=0.12.4
```

0.12.4 is quite old since 0.13.2 is out and 0.13.5 around the corner. They brought many build definition syntax changes that are supposed to ease working with builds.

I'm working with 0.13.6-SNAPSHOT launcher:

```
sandbox/so/my-game
▶ xsbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.6-SNAPSHOT
```

Starting up sbt:

```
sandbox/so/my-game                                                                                                                                                             
▶ xsbt
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.12.4 ...
...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/my-game/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[error] Android SDK not found. You might need to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT or ANDROID_HOME
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q

sandbox/so/my-game
▶ ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/apps/android-sdk-mac_x86 xsbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/my-game/project
[info] Set current project to all-platforms (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/my-game/)
>
```

`inspect` the `unmanagedJars in Compile` gives:

```
> show compile:unmanaged-jars
[info] common/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[info] desktop/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[info] android/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer(Attributed(/Users/jacek/apps/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-19/android.jar))
[info] ios/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[info] all-platforms/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 27, 2014 11:45:47 PM
```

Place the jar you want to have included in classpath:

```
sandbox/so/my-game
▶ mkdir -p android/lib/

sandbox/so/my-game
▶ touch android/lib/my-shiny-android-library.jar

sandbox/so/my-game
▶ ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/apps/android-sdk-mac_x86 xsbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/my-game/project
[info] Set current project to all-platforms (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/my-game/)
> show unmanaged-jars
[info] common/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[info] desktop/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[info] android/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer(Attributed(/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/my-game/android/lib/my-shiny-android-library.jar), Attributed(/Users/jacek/apps/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-19/android.jar))
[info] ios/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[info] all-platforms/compile:unmanaged-jars
[info]  ArrayBuffer()
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 27, 2014 11:54:40 PM
```

What's interesting is that the setting `libraryJarPath` is available as [library-jary-path](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/AndroidPlugin.scala#L165) (note the `y` in the name!):

```
val libraryJarPath = SettingKey[File]("library-jary-path")
```

To query for the value you should use the `library-jary-path` setting name in sbt shell:

```
> show library-jary-path
[info] /Users/jacek/apps/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-19/android.jar
```

To see what the following syntax is doing...

```
unmanagedJars in Compile <+= (libraryJarPath) (p => Attributed.blank(p)) map(x => x)
```

...you may want to use `consoleProject` that lets you work with the build definition on command line:

```
> console-project
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import sbt._
import Process._
import Keys._
import _root_.sbtandroid.AndroidPlugin._
import _root_.sbtrobovm.RobovmPlugin._
import LibgdxBuild._
import currentState._
import extracted._
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_55).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> libraryJarPath
res0: sbt.SettingKey[sbt.package.File] = sbt.SettingKey$$anon$4@4db9c8c3

scala> libraryJarPath(p => Attributed.blank(p))
res1: sbt.Project.Initialize[sbt.Attributed[sbt.package.File]] = sbt.Init$GetValue@2ed40452

scala> libraryJarPath.apply(p => Attributed.blank(p))
res2: sbt.Project.Initialize[sbt.Attributed[sbt.package.File]] = sbt.Init$GetValue@14e6f49b

scala> libraryJarPath.apply(p => Attributed.blank(p)) map (x => x)
res3: sbt.Project.Initialize[sbt.Task[sbt.Attributed[sbt.package.File]]] = sbt.Init$GetValue@48a4f61e

scala> libraryJarPath.apply(p => Attributed.blank(p)) map identity
res4: sbt.Project.Initialize[sbt.Task[sbt.Attributed[sbt.package.File]]] = sbt.Init$GetValue@526c8b39
```

The transformed value, after `apply` and `map`, is appended, `<+=`, to the `unmanagedJars` setting in `Compile` configuration scope.

Read [Console Project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Console-Project.html) for more details on how to work with the different settings and `get` their values.

```
scala> get(libraryJarPath in Compile in android)
res5: sbt.package.File = /Users/jacek/apps/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-19/android.jar
```

p.s. I wish I knew how to get the value of the transformed setting `res4` above.

Comment: i don't have enough rep to upvote but really appreciated your helps!